# Get all customer having limited transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have to extract all those customer names having transactions of less than 5000 each per month for 6 consecutive months and then have 3 transactions of 20,000 each on 7th month.

All the transactions for a customer will be stored in different rows.

Example: Considering customer A, Information for the customer will be stored as follows:

```
     Name | TransactionDate | Amount
1. CustomerA | 27-08-2015 | 4500
2. CustomerA | 27-09-2015 | 4500
3. CustomerA | 27-10-2015 | 4500
4. CustomerA | 27-11-2015 | 4500
5. CustomerA | 27-12-2015 | 4500
6. CustomerA | 27-01-2016 | 4500
7. CustomerA | 27-02-2016 | 20000
8. CustomerA | 27-02-2016 | 20000
9. CustomerA | 27-02-2016 | 20000
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?  Please tag the question appropriately.  I removed the extraneous tags, pending your edit.  Also, clarify what you mean by less than 5,000 per month.  Is this each transaction or the sum of the transactions?

Comment: What do you mean by "all those customer details"?  It seems your question is mostly about how to identify the name of customers that meet your criteria?

Comment: Yes @Hogan I just want to get names of the customers that meets the criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simpler query to get the result, what I wanted:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY DATEPART(MONTH,TransactionDate)) AS SrNo,
Name,Amount,DatePart(Month,TransactionDate) AS MonthNo,TransactionDate FROM TransactionTable) AS A
WHERE
(Amount <= 5000 AND SrNo < 7) OR (Amount = 20000 AND SrNo = 7)
)
SELECT A.Name AS Account_Number,A.Transaction_Date FROM
(
SELECT Name,Amount,COUNT(SrNo) As Sr,MAX(TransactionDate) AS Transaction_Date FROM CTE
WHERE SrNo = 7 AND Amount = 20000
GROUP BY Name,Amount
HAVING COUNT(srNo) = 3) AS A
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT Name,COUNT(SrNo) AS Ss FROM CTE
WHERE SrNo < 7 AND Amount <= 5000
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(srNo) = 6) AS B
ON A.Name = B.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Until you specify `SQL` flavor, I think I got a flexible and decent solution for `T-SQL`:

1) To have simpler queries, I have defined as persisted column to store month number is a convenient way:

```
create table CustomerTransaction
(
    CustomerName VARCHAR(20),
    TransactionDate DATE,
    Amount NUMERIC(18, 2),
    MonthNo AS DATEPART(yyyy, TransactionDate) * 12 + DATEPART(mm, TransactionDate) - 1 PERSISTED
)
```

If this cannot be used, you can employee date arithmetic (`DATEDIFF`), or have the exact computation inlined.

2. First CTE gets transaction data with a row number and a start month number for that group (customer and payment series).
3. For each category, small amounts and 20K (big amounts), I have selected from previous CTE applying filtering based on amount.
4. For each series apply the count criteria (6 small payments, followed by 3 big ones).
5. Join small and big payments based on customer and dates (group month is the smallest group month - 1).

The final query is the following:

```
declare @SmallAmountsLen INT = 6;
declare @BigAmountsLen INT = 3;
declare @SmallAmountThreshold NUMERIC(18, 2) = 5000
declare @BigAmount NUMERIC(18, 2) = 20000

;with AmountCte AS (
    SELECT CustomerName, TransactionDate, Amount, MonthNo, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerName ORDER BY TransactionDate) AS RowNo, 
        MonthNo - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerName ORDER BY TransactionDate) AS GroupMonthNo
    FROM CustomerTransaction
),
SmallAmountCte AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM AmountCte
    WHERE Amount < @SmallAmountThreshold 
),
BigAmountCte AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM AmountCte
    WHERE Amount = @BigAmount 
),
SmallGroupCte AS (
    select CustomerName, GroupMonthNo 
    from SmallAmountCte
    group by CustomerName, GroupMonthNo 
    having count(1) = @SmallAmountsLen
),
BigGroupCte AS (
    select CustomerName, MonthNo 
    from BigAmountCte
    group by CustomerName, MonthNo 
    having count(1) = @BigAmountsLen
)
select S.*, B.* 
from SmallGroupCte S
    join BigGroupCte B on B.CustomerName = S.CustomerName 
where B.MonthNo = S.GroupMonthNo + @SmallAmountsLen + 1
```

**[EDIT] Query without need of a computed column**

```
declare @SmallAmountsLen INT = 6;
declare @BigAmountsLen INT = 3;
declare @SmallAmountThreshold NUMERIC(18, 2) = 5000
declare @BigAmount NUMERIC(18, 2) = 20000

;with AmountCte AS (
    SELECT CustomerName, TransactionDate, Amount, DATEPART(yyyy, TransactionDate) * 12 + DATEPART(mm, TransactionDate) - 1 AS MonthNo, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerName ORDER BY TransactionDate) AS RowNo, 
        DATEPART(yyyy, TransactionDate) * 12 + DATEPART(mm, TransactionDate) - 1 - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerName ORDER BY TransactionDate) AS GroupMonthNo
    FROM CustomerTransaction
),
SmallAmountCte AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM AmountCte
    WHERE Amount < @SmallAmountThreshold 
),
BigAmountCte AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM AmountCte
    WHERE Amount = @BigAmount 
),
SmallGroupCte AS (
    select CustomerName, GroupMonthNo 
    from SmallAmountCte
    group by CustomerName, GroupMonthNo 
    having count(1) = @SmallAmountsLen
),
BigGroupCte AS (
    select CustomerName, MonthNo 
    from BigAmountCte
    group by CustomerName, MonthNo 
    having count(1) = @BigAmountsLen
)
select S.*, B.* 
from SmallGroupCte S
    join BigGroupCte B on B.CustomerName = S.CustomerName 
where B.MonthNo = S.GroupMonthNo + @SmallAmountsLen + 1
```

Comment: I do not want to create any table, I already have one with the details I have mentioned..Can this query be simplified? I am using SQL server 2012.

Comment: Also, when I set the value of MonthNo, it throws an error "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when subquery is used as an expression".

Comment: Create table is put in the answer to describe the structure I have used. First three columns are inferred based on your question data and the last one is a computed one. The computed column can be added to your existing table filled with data. Can you edit your question to include what you have done to obtain the error?

Comment: I cannot change the table schema. Can you pls modify the query to compute MonthNo with the data I have given? I just assigned the values directly in the variables you have declared and I got the error I have mentioned in the comment.

Comment: I have added version that does not required a computed column